# Pandas: return dataframe where one column's values are greater than another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Apologies if this is a duplicate but I can't seem to find a working example in the pandas docs, SO or google.

How do you return a dataframe where the values of one column are greater than the values of another?

Should be something like this: `df['A'].where(df['A']>df['B'])`

But this returns only a vector. I need the full filtered dataframe.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using `query`

```
df.query('A > B')
```

consider `df`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 2), columns=list('AB'))
df
```

[image]

***option 1***

```
df.query('A > B')
```

***option 2***

```
df[df.A.gt(df.B)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

To do `df['A'].where(df['A']>df['B'])` in pandas syntax is essentially a mask. Instead of `where` you are taking a subset of the dataframe:

`df[df['A'] > df['B']]`

[image: example]